# Use devise current_user without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to check if there is a logged user and of course if the user is an admin. I want to use the `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` methods but to use this methods I need to add

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in my application controller.

The authentication at this moment works in the admin namespace, I use it for the admin panel and I have that line in my admin_controller that inherit from application_controller. If I add

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in the application controller the user is redirected to the login page.

How can I use `user_logged_in?` without the redirect to the user login / registration page?

Comment: U have two device users ?  How you are authenticating admin? When do u want check user signed ? Explain properly

Comment: @krishnar I just have admin users. And I need to check if the user is an admin to provide some admin features on the frontend